# Good place to learn about arithmetic schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

Where is a good place to learn about arithmetic schemes? There is discussion in Eisenbud-Harris's book *The Geometry of Schemes* (and also Mumford's red book) and I hear that there is discussion in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*. But are there any other good places?

And yes, I've already checked out the related MO question:
[Examples and intuition for arithmetic schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1428/examples-and-intuition-for-arithmetic-schemes)

Comment: you might like Dino Lorenzini's Invitation to arithmetic geometry, but it is apparently not heavily about schemes.  He is a very well regarded teacher and author, so whatever is there should be acessible.  https://www.amazon.com/Invitation-Arithmetic-Geometry-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0821802674

Comment: Have you already read the sources you yourself mention?  Based on my experience, I strongly recommend you read Mumford's red book carefully, even if it does not treat everything you are interested in.  What is there is gold.  Liu's book also looks very much like what you are interested in, but I have not read it.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "arithmetic schemes" and what you want to know about them?